# Joining CTEs in Hibernate 6.2

Tags: java, hibernate, common-table-expression

Hibernate 6.2 introduced CTE support but it's unclear how to use multiple CTEs in the single HQL query.
So let's say I have City entity and the following CTE query:

```
        TypedQuery<Integer> typedQuery = em.createQuery(
        """
           with max_cities as (
             SELECT id id from City c ORDER BY population DESC
             LIMIT 20 
          ), min_cities as (
             SELECT id id from City c ORDER BY population ASC
             LIMIT 20
          )
           SELECT m1.id from max_cities m1 join min_cities m2
              on m1.id = m2.id
        """, 
        Integer.class);
```

It contains two CTEs (min_cities and max_cities). And Hibernate doesn't complain about that. But the error message is pretty clear here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve entity reference: min_cities
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.resolveHqlEntityReference(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:166)
```

So Hibernate allows to use first CTE in FROM clause but expects entity (and not CTE) in the JOIN clause.
However MySQL documentation states that joining two CTEs is pretty legal:

```
WITH
  cte1 AS (SELECT a, b FROM table1),
  cte2 AS (SELECT c, d FROM table2)
SELECT b, d FROM cte1 JOIN cte2
WHERE cte1.a = cte2.c;
```

So is joining CTEs supported in Hibernate ?

Comment: Are you looking more for an explanation of the error, or rather for a workaround?

Comment: I would like to hear the answer. Is it error or not? If that's by design then why?

Comment: It's a bug, please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-6/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov I have failed to get your point: you already have identified that behaviour is not correct, you got suggestion how to fix that, why do you ask people, who do not participate in development of your product, to perform some non-obvious steps to file a bug request?

Comment: This is just the way open source works. As a user, you have to invest your time to make it easier and hence more attractive for the library developers to fix a problem that you encounter. If you don't help, then it will take longer or possibly not be fixed at all. Engaging with the community of the open source project that your product relies on through the intended channels will surely also be beneficial for you in other ways.

Comment: In case when @Sergiy won't submit bug request, will you blame him for you software is buggy?

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a bug in [ExpectingEntityJoinDelegate#consumeIdentifier](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4bb95b7891a5f3f0b49a2e5216458f1f2fb45056/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/query/hql/internal/QualifiedJoinPathConsumer.java#L307):

```java
@Override
public void consumeIdentifier(String identifier, boolean isTerminal, boolean allowReuse) {
    if ( path.length() != 0 ) {
        path.append( '.' );
    }
    path.append( identifier );
    if ( isTerminal ) {
        final String fullPath = path.toString();
        final EntityDomainType<?> joinedEntityType = creationState.getCreationContext()
                .getJpaMetamodel()
                .resolveHqlEntityReference( fullPath );
        // here impl assumes that resolveHqlEntityReference may return nulls,
        // however it never does that. Most probably getHqlEntityReference
        // should be used instead
        if ( joinedEntityType == null ) {
            final SqmCteStatement<?> cteStatement = creationState.findCteStatement( fullPath );
            if ( cteStatement != null ) {
                join = new SqmCteJoin<>( cteStatement, alias, joinType, sqmRoot );
                creationState.getCurrentProcessingState().getPathRegistry().register( join );
                return;
            }
            throw new SemanticException( "Could not resolve join path - " + fullPath );
        }
```

BTW, cross join does work as expected, i.e.:

```
"""
   with max_cities as (
     SELECT id id from City c ORDER BY population DESC
     LIMIT 20
  ), min_cities as (
     SELECT id id from City c ORDER BY population ASC
     LIMIT 20
  )
   SELECT m1.id from max_cities m1, min_cities m2
      where m1.id = m2.id
"""
```